# Interview Question - How to handle SOAP Based and REST based Exceptions

Tags: java, rest, soap, exception

Can some one provide a very specific and to the point answer for this question ?

Comment: Are you on a phone interview? Or is this a take-home interview? :p

Comment: Was there any more context to this question? I find it a bit vague and hard to answer. In fact, if asked this question, I would ask for more clarification before answering, because I'm not 100% sure what the question they're asking is.

Comment: >>Vivin Paliath
I don't think phone interview would last so long enough that could post and get an answer from geeks like you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basics of it are, with REST you should return the proper http response code and enough information for the client to correct the error, e.g. 404 if the resource can't be found, 400 if they client sent a bad request, 500 if the server generated an exception, etc. With SOAP it looks like you always have to return a 500 Response code and a special SOAP message that says exactly what the error was (according to the SOAP spec).

Here is a [blog post](http://www.bti360.com/pages/page.asp?page_id=91491&articleId=13863) comparing the two.